# VBA AutoFiltering using multiple variable

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a problem using my autofilter. I need to filter sever values at a time.
I have the list of values on first sheet (column I2:I50) and on the second sheet I would need to filter all these values from database.

My code so far is:

```
   Dim OZ As Variant

   OZ = Array("100001", "100015")

   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=OZ, _
   Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This works perfectly so far. Now I am strugeling to setup the macro in a way, so the array refers to the Range of Sheet1 and I2:I50. Values in this range are variables calculated by functions.

Can you please help me with that?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `For` would set your OZ variable with all the 49 values from Sheet1

```
'You need 49 values I2:I50
Dim OZ(49) As Variant

For i = 0 To 48
  '1st data row starts at I2, hence + 2
  OZ(i) = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i + 2).Value
Next i


Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=OZ, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I get them into the array?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still filters a blank set of values. I had error so i had to adjust to:   OZ(i) = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I" & i + 2).Value

Comment: OK, so if the edited answer helped you, please mark it as the answer

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding it did not, I had to adjust to compesate for the error, but it still does not filter anything

Comment: Maybe what would help me would be to replace the number wtih variables reffering to certain cells:  OZ = Array("100015", "100006")

Comment: What is Sheet1.I2 value?

Comment: It is I2: 100009   I3:100006   I4:1000015

Comment: Try adding "=" to each OZ, try this line... `OZ(i) = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i + 2).Value`

Comment: The thing is when you are filtering strings like "SomeText", you can set your array `OZ(0) = "SomeText"`, but when filtering numbers, you need to set an operator > < >= = like `OZ(0) = "=100009"`

Answer (score 0):

you could use Join() and Split() functions to return a Variant array compatible for Criteria1

```
Dim OZ As Variant

OZ = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I50").Value), "|"), "|")

Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                          Criteria1:=OZ, _
                          Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

but you should avoid the *Select/Selection/Activate/ActiveXXX* pattern and use explicitly fully qualified range references

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                                               Criteria1:=Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I50").Value), "|"), "|"), _
                                               Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that advanced filter will do the job.

```
Sub ExampleCopy()
    Sheets("Table").Range("A1:B7").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Cryteria").Range("A1:15"), _
        CopyToRange:=Sheets("Result").Range("A1"), _
        Unique:=False
    Sheets("Result").Select
End Sub

'OR

Sub ExampleInPlace()
    Sheets("Table").Range("A1:A11").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace _
    , CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Cryteria").Range("A1:A6"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

The first one will copy result to a custom location. In this case to Sheet "Result" cell A1.
The second one will filter in place so in sheet "Table"

Bear in mind that in order for this to work your cryteria column header has to be the same as the data table column.

You can aslo try recording this macro using "advanced" from ribbon tab "DATA" section "Sort&filter".

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The range can be [evaluated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) to an array:

```
[Sheet2!A1:M1].AutoFilter 3, [transpose(text(Sheet1!I2:I50, "@"))], xlFilterValues
```